# How to define regions on an image and pass to tesseract-ocr?

Tags: command-line, ocr, tesseract, imagemap

How can I define regions on an image, then pass this data to **Tesseract-OCR's command-line**, so that only text within the defined regions would be extracted?

I'm guessing this may be similar to the use of an **image-map** in **HTML**.

Thank in advance for your responses.

Comment: See [this answer to a similar question, explaining the use of a UZN file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13032042/1548776).  It’s not like an image-map, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to pass in regions on an image to Tesseract.

Although it cannot be done through the command line, the Tesseract 3.02 API supports the function `SetRectangle(int left, int top, int width, int height)` that allows you to restrict the text extraction to the region specified.

It must be called after the `SetImage()` function.

Thanks again.