# Tesseract OCR limit area in command line

Tags: cmd, ocr, tesseract

Is there any way to limit the image I want to recognize by tesseract in command line? This means I want to set the coordinates of an area to "crop it".
I was trying to find it in the [usage information](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage) but I couldn't. Maybe I can do this by using a configfile. I'd appreciate any comment on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

This thread has the answer to your question:

[Tesseract: Specifying regions of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971778/tesseract-specifying-regions-of-text)

Here is the answer from that link:
Calling tesseract with parameter "-psm 4" and renaming the uzn file with the same name of the image seem works.

**Example**: If we have `C:\input.tif` and `C:\input.uzn`, we do this:

```
tesseract -psm 4 C:\input.tif C:\output
```