# tesseract specify a region to look for text

Tags: python-3.x

I am using tesseract's OCR feature. I have some screenshots and I am trying to specify a region of the image to look for text. I cannot find anything on the internet.

this is what I have for my function, but how can I make it search only in coordinates.

```python
def find_text(image):
    #scan image for text
    img_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
    #parse text to remove commas
    img_text.replace(",", "")
    #return the text
    return img_text
```

I have some coordinates where I want to search for but I don't know how to do it. I can also do it in OpenCV and make a mask with `cv2.bitwise_and()`.
If anybody knows how to specify a region of interest, please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a way with "uzn" file to indicate in which area 
of the file the text is available.

As mentioned: the uzn file should have the same name of the file with "uzn" extension.

I found a [git repo](https://github.com/jsoma/tesseract-uzn) for using uzn files with Tesseract

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13032042/2799497) which refers to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tesseract-ocr/e3lqpY0pMpw)